# Background noise while recording audio with Java/Bandpass filter as solution?

Tags: java, audio, noise

so, the last days I've been playing arround with the Google speech API to perform simple voice recognition tasks. I got one upload script - working perfectly - uploading an .wav file and receiving the said words back. I also got a good microphone. The problem is:

When listening to my microphone input from System Settings or from Audacity, there is no noise in the background. But as soon as I record with Java, my samples get inaccurate and impossible for Googles servers to parse. I already tried to smooth out the audio, with success on the result, but the servers can't process the sounds when the consonants like "T" or "K" are missing.

So, now I would like to do a bandpass filter, to filter out the frequency spectrum I want (voice spectrum from about 100Hz to 600Hz). The problem is, I don't know where to start. I would like to add the filter to the following method:

```html
        static int spikesensitivity = 50;
     static int sens = 7;
     static byte smoothedValue = 0;
     static int smoothing = 2;
     public static byte[] removeNoise(byte[] b, TargetDataLine line ){ 
             
             byte[] returnThis = new byte[b.length];

             for( int i = 0; i < b.length; i++){
              smoothedValue += (b[i] - smoothedValue) / smoothing;
              returnThis[i] = smoothedValue;
             }
                                             
             return returnThis;
     }
```

The TargetDataLines datarates are: 16000Hz, 8 bit, mono, PCM, 1 channel (1 byte per frame).

Just in case someone experienced something similar: Why is audio recording in Java so bad? All my other programs (non-Java) seem to get better voice input than I can obtain using Java. The noise is always there, no matter what frequency or setup i choose - but as soon as I try the same settings in any other program, the noise is gone :/

Thank you in advance for your time reading/replying to this :)

Line opening snippet: http://pastebin.com/qtEyNmCe

Comment: In your question you mention that your audio is 16-bit, 1 channel which is 2 bytes per frame not one. In the code snippet you are treating it as if it were 1 byte per frame. This kind of mistake can have a major impact on the audio quality.

Comment: Sorry, that was an mistake: I open my line like this, with 8 bits: http://pastebin.com/qtEyNmCe